# Javascript / JQuery scope

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a couple of functions in Javascript / Jquery where I am passing a property to one function in turn passes down to another function.

The problem that I am getting is that the property in the first function has been populated but the second function the property is underfined.

```
ExecuteSQL: function (sql, onSuccess) {                
    try {
        if (this.Database != null) {
            this.Database.transaction(function (tx) {
                tx.executeSql(sql, [], function (d, r) {
                    if (this.onSuccess) this.onSuccess(r);
                });
            });
        }
        else {
            alert("Could not execute SQL, the database connection is closed.");
        }

    }
    catch (e) {
        alert("Failed to execute SQL," + e);
    }
},
```

The onSuccess is a value at the ExecuteSQL scope but empty in the transaction scope.

Any help would be great.

Thanks
Paul.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you can just do:

```
function (d, r) { if (onSuccess) onSuccess(r); }
```

Just to make the check explicitly for function you can do:

```
function (d, r) { if (typeof onSuccess === 'function') onSuccess(r); }
```

Since `onSuccess` is a variable that holds the function reference that is defined in the scope of the function `ExecuteSQL` you can just access it as is  inside the callback and it is not associated as a property of the instance, so `this.onSuccess` doesn't fetch you anything (Leaving the fact that `this` is not the `this` inside the `ExecuteSQL` function ).

Comment: Hi, thank you, I did try that before but could get it to work either but this was because of another JS problem. Thanks.